# Get path of file or directory that caused UnauthorizedAccessException when using Get-Acl

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using Powershell command `$TargetFiles = Get-Childitem $TargetPath -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | Get-Acl`.

If this command fails because user running it does not have enought permissions on some file or directory the following error is raised:

```
Get-Acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
At B:\PS\Script.ps1:20 char:50
+     $TargetFiles = Get-Childitem $TargetPath -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

When handling this exception I would like to print out path of file or directory that caused the permission error.

How can I get the path of file or directory causing this error?

I have tried using commands such as `Get-PSCallStack` and looked into variables like `$StackTrace` but could not find this information from them.

Version of Powershell I am using:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems `Get-Acl` is the code throwing the exception, and whilst it's the same type of exception as we'd see returned by `Get-ChildItem`, the message is different (`Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation` instead of `Access to the path 'c:\whatever' is denied`), and it does not carry the offending path in its data.

The fix is this:

```
try {
    $TargetFiles = $TargetPath | Get-Childitem -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object{$_ | Get-Acl -ErrorAction Stop}
} catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] {
    $pathWithProblem = $_.TargetObject
    #do what you like with it after this
    $descriptionOfProblem = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Warning "$descriptionOfProblem : $pathWithProblem"
    throw
}
```

This looks a bit silly; since we're just wrapping the call to `Get-ACL` in a `foreach` block; the logic of which is taken care of by the pipeline input anyway.  I'm pretty sure this unusual behaviour is caused by a bug in the PS logic for generating exception information, but this wrapper does seem to work around your issue.

Comment: This helped me to understand the problem I am facing. However the property `TargetObject` remains empty when I try to use this solution.

Comment: In that case you're probably best off adding a catch block within the foreach / around the `Get-ACL` call, setting `$currentPath = $_.FullName` before the call then using this new variable to access the path within the catch block.

Comment: ps. found this thread, but sadly no conclusion for the PowerShell approach: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/5m78j8/im_trying_to_generate_a_list_of_foldersfiles_i/

Comment: I used catch block aroud `Get-Acl` and `$_.FullName` variable according to your suggestion. With those I was I able to get the information about files that were causing permission errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$Error` automatic variable to take a look on process that hit exception. Like so:

```
$TargetFiles = Get-Childitem $TargetPath -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop

$Error[0]
$Error[0].ErrorRecord.CategoryInfo
$Error[0].ErrorRecord.CategoryInfo.TargetName
```

Comment: I was able to find the exception and some details from `$Error` variable but not refence to the path of file or dir that caused the error.

Comment: @MadocComadrin, you could drill down the `$Error` object and look for `$Error[0].ErrorRecord.CategoryInfo` it has the information you need.

Comment: NB: It seems that this works when the error is `Access to the path 'c:\whatever' is denied`,but not when the exception is `Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation`.

Comment: I got this working when using `Get-Childitem` without `Get-Acl`.